# What is the meaning of "that sorrel of yourn hadn't hurt himself

Tags: phrase-meaning, spoken-english

I'm reading O. Henry *The Roads We Take*, and there is the phrase, that doesn't make any sense for me.

> Shark Dodson got up and leaned against a tree. "**I'd a good deal
>   rather that sorrel of yourn hadn't hurt himself, Bob,**" he said ...

Comment: Research the terms *sorrel horse* and *yourn* and tell us what you find.

Comment: For your own peace of mind, none of this is in standard usage.  I'm a native, educated speaker and out of context I'd have no idea what this meant.

Comment: For some reason, I thought "sorrel of yourn" was a euphemism for son of bitch. :P

Comment: @Davo, thanks a lot, 'sorrel <b>horse</b>' was the right part of what I needed to get the sense!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Yourn* is a dialect form of *yours*—it has the same *-n* affix as *mine*, which shows up in the corresponding dialect forms *hisn*, *hern*, *ourn*. *That sorrel of yourn* = *That sorrel of yours*.

So Shark is expressing a wish ("I'd a good deal rather") that Bob's sorrel (a chestnut-colored horse) had not "hurt himself"—that is, had not been hurt.

Comment: There's something of "garden path" aspect to the cited text, in that in the *written* form, we (native speakers *and* learners) might be momentarily misled into parsing ***that*** as an optional (conjunction?) as it would be in, say, *I would rather [**that**] you did it*. Which issue wouldn't normally arise in the spoken version, since if it *were* that optional element, it would be de-stressed, with only a neutral vowel.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fersher. But it's a very short path, since it's evident almost immediately that *that* has to act as the obligatory determiner on *sorrel*.

Comment: Offhand the only example I can think of for a written form where the "ambiguity" can't be resolved almost immediately is *Would you rather that Man didn't exist?* - where only the capitalisation (or lack thereof) tells us whether the question asks about mankind in general or some context-specific person. But I'm sure someone could come up with a similar example where it would be impossible to say with certainty what was meant just by looking at the words as written.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But **sorrel** is subspecies and **Man** is species. We wouldn't say *Would you rather that bulldog didn't exist?* Or *Would you rather that pinto didn't exist?* if we wanted to refer to the class not  an instance member.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That requires knowledge of the noun in question; I'd never heard of sorrel = type of horse, so my first thought was [the herb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorrel), and plant names can generally be used to refer to the whole variety, so someone who didn't like the flavour might well say "I would rather that sorrel didn't exist". (It's not a species vs sub-species thing, more animal vs plant I think - "I would rather that dog didn't exist" makes no more sense than "...bulldog...". "Man" meaning "mankind" is something rather different.)

Comment: @IMSop: What is to be said when you think of 'herb' even though the sentence says "hurt himself"?  I don't know how to respond when the basis of your argument is "I didn't know what it meant".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo We were talking about garden path sentences. Up until "I'd a good deal rather that sorrel ..." the "herb" interpretation makes sense; without knowing "yourn", "sorrel of yourn" could still be a noun phrase that worked in this interpretation, as in "I'd a good deal rather that Richard of York..." [I'm not sure why you feel the need to "respond" to my "argument", I was just expanding on an observation another commenter had made that there is "something a garden path aspect to the cited text".]

Comment: @IMSoP: OK. I do see that  after "I'd rather" you might well expect **that** to be the clause subordinator not the determiner, and I grant that if *readers* didn't know what **sorrel** was, they could think it analogous to **oregano**, not requiring a determiner, and thus not realize there was a parsing issue until they reached **hurt himself**.  I emphasize reader because in speech, the parsing rhythms would identify **that** as  determiner not subordinator:  *{I'd a good deal rather} {syntactic pause} {that sorrel of yourn}...*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Indeed, which is exactly what FumbleFingers said in the first comment. :)

Comment: @IMSoP: But is that comment relevant given the fact that the sorrel's injury has already been mentioned in the story and OP would have encountered the word **sorrel** before reaching this point in the story?

Comment: @IMSoP: Ty for taking up the cudgel on my behalf! I must admit that [that?! :] meaning of ***sorrel = herb*** didn't occur to me before. But it's inspired me to realise I can honestly say *I'd rather that **aniseed** wasn't used to make Pernod* (can't stand the stuff! :). Now I'll just have to wait for a chance to say that in a context where someone else could reasonably reply with ***That** aniseed isn't the real thing! Pernod use **star anise**. You'd like it just fine if they used **this** aniseed!* (while pointing to some Common Anise, aka *pimpinella anisum*).

Comment: (except my entire point wouldn't apply in that scenario, since the potential ambiguity rests entirely on it being a *written* form where you don't know which words carry stress!)